# How can I use Twilio as a SIP trunk for my Asterisk to send and receive SMS for my Bria/Xlite?

Tags: sms, sip, asterisk, twilio, sip-server

I recently manage to do inbound/outbound calling on twilio using my Asterisk server, thanks to this topic on stackoverflow.

[How can I use Twilio as a SIP trunk for my Asterisk to make and receive calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848222/how-can-i-use-twilio-as-a-sip-trunk-for-my-asterisk-to-make-and-receive-calls)

Now the only thing left is SMS, how can i send/recieve SMS using my Bria?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that Twilio doesn't support SIP MESSAGE method. According to this doc http://www.twilio.com/docs/sip and links in it, you can do only voice calls.

Comment: Hello Jc, thanks for the reply, but i believe Bria supports SMS, which is different from SIP/IM messages.

Comment: @PageLiker, the answer from CounterPath (Bria developers) support:
 https://support.counterpath.com/responses/how_to_get_sip_sms_working_on_bria_android_configuration_provider

"Bria supports SMS service through the SIP SIMPLE protocol."

Unfortunately, I don't think that Twilio can work with SIP SIMPLE.