# Use Twilio as a SMS gateway to SIM on a phone?

Tags: java, android, twilio, sms, api-gateway

In the [broader context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2570410/22063140) of sending SMS with Java, can Twilio be used to send messages from the same phone number as is on the SIM chip on a physical phone?

Something along the lines of https://sms.ilpostino.com.ar/ in SMS functionality, where there's a corresponding app so that the phone itself is used as a gateway.

Twilio seems to be [strictly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26011313/22063140) an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If you wish to use the number that was previous "on" your SIM card, you can request to [port this number to Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179348-Porting-a-Phone-Number-to-Twilio).

While it's possible to make calls from [verified numbers](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135427-What-s-the-Difference-Between-a-Verified-Phone-Number-and-a-Twilio-Phone-Number-#:%7E:text=Capabilities%3A%20Verified%20phone%20numbers%20can,route%20through%20your%20original%20provider.), it's not possible to send SMS from these sender IDs.